# Why wait(), notify() and notifyAll() are in Object class

Tags: java, multithreading

As these methods will be used w.r.t threading. No mater how you create thread, you will create an object of `Thread` class or object of subclass of `Thread` class. Then why these methods are in `Object` and not in `Thread` class?

Comment: That's the most duplicated title I've ever seen..

Answer (score 0):

If all these methods present in `Thread` class, then if you are going to create a thread implementing `Runnable` interface, then this method is directly not available.
If these methods are present in `Runnable` interface, then always we have to provide body for this.
Thats why they kept these methods inside `Object` class.